QGIS k-means fails - Loading resulting layers The following layers were not correctly generated
I'm using QGIS 3.22.14.
I'm trying to k-means clusters on raster I have. The tool runs but the errors are not loading with the following log and error:
Loading grid: C:/Users/tomi/AppData/Local/Temp/5/processing_ECmygI/a5fskcxnds7592848592/my_raster.sgrd...
failed
K-Means Clustering for Grids: could not initialize data objects
Error: executing tool [K-Means Clustering for Grids]

C:\Windows\system32>exit
Execution completed in 587.00 seconds (9 minutes 47 seconds)
Results:
{'CLUSTER': 'C:/Users/tomi/AppData/Local/Temp/5/processing_ECmygI/75szjsdjsnvdjdkahdfkakajeifjfjvn/CLUSTER.sdat',
'STATISTICS': 'C:/Users/tomi/AppData/Local/Temp/5/processing_ECmygI/dflkjcvlkcxmklcxmvksdjfojo/STATISTICS.shp'}

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.
• C:/Users/tomi/AppData/Local/Temp/5/processing_ECmygI/75szjsdjsnvdjdkahdfkakajeifjfjvn/CLUSTER.sdat
• C:/Users/reut/AppData/Local/Temp/5/processing_ECmygI/dflkjcvlkcxmklcxmvksdjfojo/STATISTICS.shp
You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.

I have read that this might be result of not having SAGA/not enabling it.
I have downloaded SAGA, and also I have enabled it:

What could be the reason for that? How can I use the K-means clusters tool on raster using QGIS?
Edit:
I have tried the solution but still have the same error, cannot run it :


I'm using QGIS 3.34 LTR, so for me sagaprovider was broken upon installation, since the plugin is now deprecated (?). What I did was install SAGA nextgen provider plugin, and add the binaries manually (https://sourceforge.net/p/saga-gis/wiki/Binary%20Packages/), making sure to add the path to the folder with the saga files. You might also need to do the same for Orpheus Toolbox (saga would keep giving errors until I updated OTB): https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing/3rdParty.html#otb-applications
Since sagaprovider broke from QGIS 3.30 onwards I would have expected to work with your version. Regardless, you can try the nextgen plugin, and see if it works.


I'm not sure what the exact problem is, but it doesn't find the metadata file, so the plugin is disabled by default. You can find some information about it here
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/52160

the issue is still there, since on my fresh install of qgis I still can't use sagaprovider. this is the reason I installed saga nextgen

I have tried it but still same issue... I thought maybe if I will downoad old version of QGIS it might work, what do you think?

you're already using an "older" version of QGIS, where the sagaprovider plugin isn't broken, so the version might not be the issue. when you run the k-means clustering make sure you are using it from the sagang plugin, and not still from sagaprovider, in case you have both active. I would also get errors until I had OTB enabled and running, so maybe try to configure that, too. to a lesser extent maybe also take out the inner saga-9.4.0_x64 folder, and only use that one, instead of a folder inside a folder? I used k-means on a raster just now, and it worked well

also, make sure the folder you have the saga 9.4.0_x64 has read/write permission. sometimes the Users folder doesn't allow for that unless you have admin privileges (?)
